# Nhibernate equal restriction on guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, guid

I have a class, Comapny, with userId as system.Guid, i want to filter that company (userId is not the primary key), but when I do it like this:

```
     List<Company> list =
            session.CreateCriteria<Company>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserId", userId))
            .List<Company>().ToList();
```

The list is returning empty even though there are rows in the db with that property.

I tried doing it like this:

```
        Company companyResult = null;

        list.ForEach(delegate (Company company)
                         {
                             if (company.UserId.Equals(userId))
                             {
                                 if (companyResult == null)
                                 {
                                     companyResult = company;
                                 }
                             }
                         });

        return companyResult;
```

and it works, is there a reason why Nhibernate eq won't work on this Guid?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the `Query` method?

```
var list = session.Query<Company>().Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do to really investigate this, is to switch on show-sql, apparently you are retrieving something different from the database then you think?